# htaccess - redirect entire domain to specific url on new domain

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I've setup a number of htaccess rules to redirect a large number of old domains to one new domain. Each old domain points to a specific page on the new website. For example:

`olddomainlocation1.com` redirects to `newdomain.com/location1`

`olddomainlocation2.com` redirects to `newdomain.com/location2`
etc.

The rewrite rule redirects as expected if you visit an old domain name without any path in the url, but when I visit an old domain with a path in the url it doesn't work.

eg. `olddomainlocation1.com/index.html`, my rewrite rule doesn't work, I just end up on `newdomain.com/index.html` (which doesn't exist)

Here is an example of my htaccess rule. Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{http_host} ^www.olddomainlocation1.co.uk [NC,OR]
  RewriteCond %{http_host} ^olddomainlocation1.co.uk [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://newdomain.co.uk/location1/ [R,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

**UPDATE**

I have updated the rule now which seems to be closer to working, but it's not quite there yet.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomainlocation1.co.uk$ [NC,OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomainlocation1.co.uk$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ https://newdomain.co.uk/location1/ [R,NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Adding $ to the end of my RewriteCond makes sure the rule runs on pages like /index.html.

When I test this rule on https://technicalseo.com/tools/htaccess/ and it's telling me that the redirect should be in place, but when I test the redirect, the url isn't changing for me in my browser.

**UPDATE 2**

Further update: I do have WordPress specific rules above the domain redirects, which could be causing an issue, here is that code:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^newdomain.co.uk$
  RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Comment: "I just end up on `newdomain.com/index.html`" - The rule you posted does not do that. So there would seem to be "something else" going on here. Do you have other directives? Is it perhaps a cached redirect? Please confirm the 3xx HTTP status you are seeing in the redirect. Do you have access to the server config? Where do all these (old and new) domains point to? Do they all point to this one place, the same as `newdomain.com`?

Comment: Regarding your update... this is really no different to your original rule. Adding `$` to the end of your `RewriteCond` makes no difference (in fact it now won't work on FQDN). To stress my point above... there is "something else" going on here. If you are seeing a redirect to `newdomain.com/index.html` then you have another rule or some server-side script that is doing that. You need to find the bit of code that is performing the redirect you are seeing, because the rule you posted cannot possibly result in the redirect you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I do have some WordPress specific code above these redirects, which may be conflicting? I've posted the code in an update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Further update: I do have WordPress specific rules above the domain redirects, which could be causing an issue

Yes, that is certainly the problem. The WordPress specific rules (ie. the WordPress front-controller) should appear later in the file. The external redirect needs to go near the top of the `.htaccess` file, *before* the WordPress front-controller. Order matters.

The problem is that a request of the form `/index.html` (which does not exist) is rewritten to the WordPress engine *before* your redirect (that appears later) is able to process the request. So this will ultimately trigger a WordPress generated 404 instead of a redirect.

For example:

```
# Redirect olddomain to page on newdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomainlocation1\.co\.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://newdomain.co.uk/location1/ [R=302,L]

# BEGIN WordPress
# :
```

*Aside:* I've combined your 2 conditions into a single `RewriteCond` directive.

You do not need the `<IfModule>` wrapper nor repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive.

Comment: Thanks @MrWhite, that's worked a treat. Thanks for your help!